# Why openfire return redundant message archiving?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am using these technologies:

- openfire version: 3.9.3
- Monitoring Service plugin: 1.4.2
- strophe.js: 1.1.3

I sent iq below for querying message archiving

```xml
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" id="2:retrieve">
   <retrieve xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="room123@conference.gunblues" start="2015-01-20T06:53:01.831Z">
      <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm" />
   </retrieve>
</iq>
```

the result I want:

```xml
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="2:retrieve" to="user1@gunblues/e6432422">
   <chat xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="room123@conference.gunblues" start="2015-01-20T06:53:01.831Z">
      <from secs="0" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>abc</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="1" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a2</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="2" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a3</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="3" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a4</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="4" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a5</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="5" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a6</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="7" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a7</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="7" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a8</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="8" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a9</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="9" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a10</body>
      </from>
      <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
         <first index="0">0</first>
         <last>9</last>
         <count>10</count>
      </set>
   </chat>
</iq>
```

but server returned redundant result:

```xml
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="2:retrieve" to="user1@gunblues/e6432422">
   <chat xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="room123@conference.gunblues" start="2015-01-20T06:53:01.831Z">
      <from secs="0" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>abc</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="0" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>abc</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="0" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>abc</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="1" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a2</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="1" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a2</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="1" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a2</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="2" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a3</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="2" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a3</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="2" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a3</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="3" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a4</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="3" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a4</body>
      </from>
      <from secs="3" jid="user2@gunblues">
         <body>a4</body>
      </from>
      <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
         <first index="0">0</first>
         <last>11</last>
         <count>12</count>
      </set>
   </chat>
</iq>
```

Comment: FWIW, the monitoring plugin is pretty buggy when it comes to retrieving archived messages.